# extract value of an assignment expression

Tags: bash, sed, awk, text-manipulation

Suppose I have this string:

```
a b c d e=x f g h i
```

What's the best* way to extract the value `x` from `e=x` using only Linux commands (like `sed` and `awk`)?

**The definition of "best" is up to you.*

Answer (score 3):

How about this, using just Bash:

```
$ s="a b c d e=x f g h i"
$ s="${s#*=}"
$ echo "${s%% *}"
x
```

The used parameter expansions are documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Another one using `sed`:

```
$ s="a b c d e=x f g h i"
$ echo "$s" | sed 's|.*=\([^[:space:]]*\).*|\1|'
x
```

Again with `sed`:

```
$ s="a b c d e=x f g h i"
$ echo "$s" | sed 's|.*=||; s|[[:space:]].*||'
x
```

Another one using `cut`:

```
$ s="a b c d e=x f g h i"
$ echo "$s" | cut -d = -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1
x
```

My personal favourite is the first one: it only needs Bash and it does not launch any additional processes.

EDIT:

As per the comments, here are the expressions above, modified to match `e` specifically:

```
$ s="a b c d e=x f g h i"
$ s="${s#*e=}"; echo "${s%% *}"
x
$ s="a b c d e=x f g h i"
$ echo "$s" | sed 's|.*\be=\([^[:space:]]*\).*|\1|'
x
$ echo "$s" | sed 's|.*\be=||; s|[[:space:]].*||'
x
```

Comment: Do: `$ s="${s#*e=}"` for specifically the e value if more than one can have an =

Comment: @evan:agreed - this could also be modified accordingly in all the other cases. But the OP should have a more complete test input if he wanted us to handle that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Will `grep` do? Assuming I understand your question correctly:

```
echo $s | grep -oP '(?<=e\=)[^ ]*'
```

where `s='a b c d e=x f g h i'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner using `sed` and `awk`:

```
$ echo 'a b c d e=x f g h i' | sed 's/=/\n/' | awk '{ getline v; split(v, arr); for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i, "=", arr[i] }'
a = x
b = f
c = g
d = h
e = i
```

Process is to split into two lines at the `=` using `sed`, then loop through the columns in both lines simultaneously using `awk`

Comment: Thanks, although I realized after reading other answers I might have misinterpreted the question, oops!  This still seems potentially useful so I'll leave it up.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bash >= 3.2 regexes:

```
string='a b c d e=x f g h i'
pattern=' [^ ]*=([^ ]*) '
[[ $string =~ $pattern ]]
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

### gAWK

```
/=/ {match($0, /\<\w+=\w+\>/, a);print a[0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you Linux system have Ruby

```
$ echo 'a b c d e=x f g h i' | ruby -e 'puts gets.scan(/=(\w+)/)[0][0]'
x
```

or alternative

```
$ echo 'a b c d e=x f g h i'| tr "=" "\n"| awk 'NR==2{print $1}'
x
```

Answer (score 0):

An all bash solution which can handle all those variables (not sure of the ultimate goal of this) cleanly

```
STRING="a b c d e=x f g h i"
export IFS="="
while read -d ' ' var value; do
 echo "$var is $value"
done <<< "$STRING"
```

Answer (score 0):

With a modern perl:

```
$ perl -nE 'm/e=(\S*)/; say $1'
```

or

```
$ perl -pe 's/.*e=(\S*).*/$1/'
```

With old perl:

```
$ perl -ne 'm/e=(\S*)/; print "$1\n"'
```